# How to get UISwitch with its tag?

Tags: ios, tags, uiswitch

I have a function that i call each time i open the controller to draw for me UISwitch.

```
 int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < daysArray.count ; i++)
    {

        UISwitch * daysSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(255, y, 20, 20)];
        [daysSwitch setTag:i];
        [daysSwitch setOn:YES];
         [daysSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
              [self.availableTimesScrollView addSubview:daysSwitch];

        y = y+ 130;


    }
```

I am trying to set some of those UISwitch to On or Off according to their tag.

```
 UISwitch * switch = (UISwitch *) [self.view viewWithTag:0]
[switch setOn:NO];
```

but it doesn't change or seem to affect it.

So if this is not the right answer to get the tag of UISwitch to set it to on or off , How can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default tag for a view is 0.

You're adding these `UISwitch` instances to `self.availableTimesScrollView` but calling `viewWithTag:` on `self.view`. This method will return the nearest ancestor with that given tag, so it's probably returning `self.availableTimesScrollView`.

Assuming your view hierarchy looks like below, the nearest ancestor with tag 0 is `self.availableTimesScrollView`.

```
self.view
    self.availableTimesScrollView (tag 0)
         switch1 (tag 0)
         switch2 (tag 1)
         switch3 (tag 2)
         ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding your switches to `self.availableTimesScrollView` so when retrieving it you have to reference that scroll view:

```
UISwitch * switch = (UISwitch *) [self.availableTimesScrollView viewWithTag:0]
```